# ¿Se puede descomprimir sus datos más de una vez?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, gradient

Estoy tratando de hacer un algoritmo de descenso de gradiente para predecir el beta de una relacion linal.

Zip mis datos al principio con `data = zip(x,y)` en las iteraciones que hago para mejorar el gradiente, dezip mis datos una vez al principio, al calcular el error cuadrado.

```
value = sum(target_fn(x_i, y_i, theta) for x_i,y_i in data)
```

Los dezippor segunda vez al calcular el gradiente, pero en ese momento parece que los `data` están vacíos:

```
print("[e for e in data_here]: ", [e for e in data])
for x_i, y_i in in_random_order(data):
      gradient_i = gradient_fn(x_i, y_i, theta)
```

Devuleve:

```
e for e in data]:  []


import math

def make_matrix(num_rows, num_cols, entry_fn):
  """renvoie une num_rows x num_cols matrice
  où l'entrée i,j est l'entrée entry_fn(i, j)
  """
  return [[entry_fn(i,j)
          for j in range(num_cols)]
          for i in range(num_rows)] 

def mean(x):
  return sum(x)/len(x)

def get_column(A,j):
  return [A_i[j]
          for A_i in A]

def de_mean(x):
  """translate x en soustrayant sa moyenne (donc le résultat a une moyenne de 0)"""
  x_bar = mean(x)
  return [x_i - x_bar for x_i in x] 

def sum_of_squares(v):
  """calcule la somme des éléments carrés dans v"""
  return sum(v_i ** 2 for v_i in v)

def variance(x):
  """asssumes x has at least two elements"""
  n = len(x)
  deviations = de_mean(x)
  return sum_of_squares(deviations)/(n-1)

def standard_deviation(x):
  return math.sqrt(variance(x))

def scale(data_matrix):
  """renvoie la moyenne et l'écart type de chaque colonne"""
  num_rows, num_cols = np.array(data_matrix).shape
  means = [mean(get_column(data_matrix, j))
          for j in range(num_cols)]
  stdevs = [standard_deviation(get_column(data_matrix,j))
          for j in range(num_cols)]
  return means, stdevs

def rescale(data_matrix):
  """rescales the input data so that each column
  has mean 0 and standard deviation 1
  leaves alone column with no stdev"""
  means, stdevs = scale(data_matrix)

  def rescaled(i, j):
    if stdevs[j]>0:
      return (data_matrix[i][j] - means[j])/stdevs[j]
    else:
      return data_matrix[i][j]

  num_rows, num_cols = np.array(data_matrix).shape
  return make_matrix(num_rows, num_cols, rescaled)

def dot(v, w):
  """v_i * w_1 + ... + v_n * w_n"""
  return sum(v_i*w_i
             for v_i, w_i in zip(v, w))

def in_random_order(data):
  """generator that returns the elements of data in random order"""
  indexes = [i for i, _ in enumerate(data)]

  print("indexes: ", indexes)
  random.shuffle(indexes)
  for i in indexes:
    yield data[i]

def predict(x_i, beta):
  """assumes that the first element of each x_i is 1"""
  print("beta: ", beta)
  return dot(x_i, beta)

def error(x_i, y_i, beta):
  return y_i - predict(x_i, beta)

def squared_error(x_i,y_i, beta):
  return error(x_i, y_i, beta)**2

def squared_error_gradient(x_i, y_i, theta):
  alpha, beta = theta
  return [-2 * error(alpha, beta, x_i, y_i),
          -2 * error(alpha, beta, x_i, y_i) * x_i]


def minimize_stochastic(target_fn, gradient_fn, x, y, theta_0, alpha_0=0.01):
  data = zip(x, y)
  theta = theta_0
  alpha = alpha_0
  # min_theta = min_value = None, float("inf")
  min_theta, min_value = None, float("inf")
  iterations_with_no_impovment = 0

  # si on va au dela de 100 itérations, on arrête
  while iterations_with_no_impovment<100:
    value = sum(target_fn(x_i, y_i, theta) for x_i,y_i in data)
    print("value < min_value: ", value < min_value)
    if value < min_value:
      # si on a trouvé un novueau minimum, on le stocke
      # et on retourne au step original
      min_theta, min_value = theta, value
      iterations_with_no_impovment = 0
      alpha = alpha_0
    else:
      #sinon on est pas en train d'améliorer, donc on réduit le pas
      iterations_with_no_impovment +=1
      alpha*=0.9

    print("[e for e in data_here]: ", [e for e in data])
    # et on prend un pas de gradient pour chacun des points
    for x_i, y_i in in_random_order(data):
      print("x_i, y_i: ", x_i, y_i)
      gradient_i = gradient_fn(x_i, y_i, theta)
      theta = vector_substract(theta, scalar_multiply(alpha, gradient_i))

    return min_theta

def estimate_beta(x, y):
  beta_initial = [random.random() for x_i in x[0]]
  return minimize_stochastic(squared_error,
                             squared_error_gradient,
                             x,y,
                             beta_initial,
                             0.001)
```

En efecto cuando intento:

```
trans_df = pd.DataFrame(zip(ones,experience,salary, y),columns=column_names).fillna(df.mean())
trans_df.to_csv("data.csv")
ones = trans_df['ones'].tolist()
experience = trans_df['experience'].tolist()
salary = trans_df['salary'].tolist()
column_names = trans_df['addicted vistors'].tolist()
```

Me devuelve:

```
...

beta:  [0.6649909153021386, 0.6217701542674371, 0.9173558392014559]
beta:  [0.6649909153021386, 0.6217701542674371, 0.9173558392014559]
value < min_value:  False
e for e in data]:  []
indexes:  []
beta:  None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-224-19238b5630cb> in <module>()
      3 print("len(rescaled_x): ", len(rescaled_x), " len(beta)", len(y))
      4 beta = estimate_beta(rescaled_x, y) # issue there
----> 5 predictions = [predict(x_i, beta) for x_i in rescaled_x]
      6 
      7 plt.scatter(predictions, y)

2 frames
<ipython-input-223-4d888b375cce> in dot(v, w)
     61   """v_i * w_1 + ... + v_n * w_n"""
     62   return sum(v_i*w_i
---> 63              for v_i, w_i in zip(v, w))
     64 
     65 def in_random_order(data):

TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration
```

Aqui estan [los datos de `trans_df`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11nTG3vgX5VQJPf5oqwCw6R82n5TC1T2X/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: El error es que estas usando `zip(v, w)`, pero `v` o `w` no es iterable. Revisa que argumentos estás pasando.

Comment: Comentario al margen: zip no tiene nada que ver con comprimir. El término hacer referencia al término inglés para "cremallera", porque asocia uno con uno los dos iterables que le pasas (igual que una cremallera enlaza cada pareja de enganches)